# autocomplete tags in textarea?

Tags: 7, ajax, taxonomy-terms

I need a tagging functionality for my content type. The normal term reference tag autocomplete widget has a problem, because I can't find a way to use textarea instead of textfield for it. I would need textarea to be able to see all tags while typing them. One node will have 10-20 tags, some of which are not just words, but expressions. So it all takes place and textfield is not acceptable.

How to enable entering tags into textarea with autocomplete?

Comment: Try this module. It will give you same option to search inside text area
[Ats.js](https://www.drupal.org/project/atjs "Ats.js")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Autocomplete Delux](https://www.drupal.org/project/autocomplete_deluxe) module. After installing and enabling the module you can change your tag field widget in your form.

**Autocomplete Delux:**

> This is an enhanced autocomplete element, that uses the JQuery UI autocomplete. It will also implement a widget for taxonomy.